# Scala List.diff .intersect and .union not working as expected

Tags: scala

Using the code below yields the following:

```
List(a, b)
List()
List(a, b, b, c)
```

What I want is of course a result like this:

```
List(a)
List(b)
List(a, b, b, c)
```

I think this is because diff union and intersect work with respect to "==".
The problem is then that the "=="-operator is final and cannot be overridden in class "Test".

How could I achieve the result I expect?

Here comes the used code:

```
package scalatest;

public class JStringHolder {
String s = null;

public JStringHolder(String newString){
    s = newString;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return s;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("SHEQ " + this.s + " AND " + ((JStringHolder)obj).s + " " + this.s.equals(((JStringHolder)obj).s));
    return this.s.equals(((JStringHolder)obj).s);
}
}
```

And the scala code to be executed:

```
package scalatest

object ListTest {

  trait AbstractTest 
  case class Test(stringHolder: scalatest.JStringHolder) extends AbstractTest {
    override def toString = stringHolder.toString()
    override def equals(ot: Any) : Boolean = {
      return stringHolder.equals(ot.asInstanceOf[Test].stringHolder)
    }

  }

  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val l1 = List(Test(new JStringHolder("a")), Test(new JStringHolder("b")))
    val l2 = List(Test(new JStringHolder("b")), Test(new JStringHolder("c")))
    println (l1.diff(l2))
    println (l1.intersect(l2))
    println (l1.union(l2))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you should override the hashCode Method in a way, that two instances show the same hashCode, when you think they are the same. Only if the hashCode is the same, the equals method will be called, otherwise two instances are not the same(at least in the sense of List.diff and intersect).

Using the code below will achieve the result I want:

```
List(a)
List(b)
List(a, b, b, c)
```

Here comes the used code:

```
package scalatest;

public class JStringHolder {
String s = null;

public JStringHolder(String newString){
    s = newString;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return s;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.s.equals(((JStringHolder)obj).s);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return s.hashCode();
}
}
```

And the scala code to be executed:

```
package scalatest

object ListTest {

  trait AbstractTest 
  case class Test(stringHolder: scalatest.JStringHolder) extends AbstractTest {
    override def toString = stringHolder.toString()
    override def equals(ot: Any) : Boolean = {
      return stringHolder.equals(ot.asInstanceOf[Test].stringHolder)
    }
    override def hashCode() : Int = {
      stringHolder.hashCode()
    }       
  }

  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val l1 = List(Test(new JStringHolder("a")), Test(new JStringHolder("b")))
    val l2 = List(Test(new JStringHolder("b")), Test(new JStringHolder("c")))
    println (l1.diff(l2))
    println (l1.intersect(l2))
    println (l1.union(l2))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure: maybe a bug if the implementation of diff? Using the deprecated `--` instead of `diff` actually works for me. `Set` instead of `List` works too.

I have no answer (just the suggestion to use Set as a workaround) but I'm adding my own tests here, in case they can help someone else to come back with an answer:

```
// re-implementing JStringHolder in scala
// to show that this is not java-specific
class JStringHolder(val st: String) {
    override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
        case t: JStringHolder => this.st == t.st
        case _ => false
    }
}
case class Test(stringHolder: JStringHolder) {
    override def equals(that: Any) : Boolean = that match {
        case t: Test => this.stringHolder == t.stringHolder
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

now in the REPL (scala 2.9.0.1):

```
scala> List(Test(new JStringHolder("a")), Test(new JStringHolder("b")))
res0: List[Test] = List(a, b)

scala> List(Test(new JStringHolder("c")), Test(new JStringHolder("b")))
res1: List[Test] = List(c, b)

scala> res0 diff res1
res2: List[Test] = List(a, b)
```

-- is deprecated but works

```
scala> res0 -- res1
<console>:13: warning: method -- in class List is deprecated: use `list1 filterN
ot (list2 contains)` instead
       res0 -- res1
            ^
res3: List[Test] = List(a)
```

doing it with filterNot, like the deprecation warning suggests, works too

```
scala> res0 filterNot (res1 contains )
res4: List[Test] = List(a)
```

Also, showing that everything works with `Set`

```
scala> Set(Test(new JStringHolder("a")), Test(new JStringHolder("b")))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Test] = Set(a, b)

scala> Set(Test(new JStringHolder("b")), Test(new JStringHolder("c")))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Test] = Set(b, c)

scala> res0 diff res1
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Test] = Set(a)

scala> res0 union res1
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Test] = Set(a, b, c)

scala> res0 intersect res1
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Test] = Set(b)
```

Comment: After a lot of trying i figured it to be the hashCode method. If you Override it correctly. The code above will work just fine. Thank you all for your answers! Must be a hashtable in the background doing all the work.

Comment: @John: you should put your correct code in an answer and mark it correct (for others in the future). I still think there is something strange going on, since equalities for JStringHolder and Test seem to work (`new JStringHolder("a")==new JStringHolder("a")` is true, `Test(new JStringHolder("a"))==Test(new JStringHolder("a"))` is true...)

Comment: I wanted to insert it as an answer, but I am not allowed to answer in as less than 8 hours after submitting the question. I will add the code later... You are right, if you use "==" for just a StringHolder it will work. The problem is the diff and intersect method of the List. They seem to use the hashCode to differentiate instances...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much choice beyond encapsulating these values on something with a reasonable `equals` method.

Comment: the whole issue is that you need to override the `hashCode` method. It it really silly but this is how it works at the current time. Hope scala updates `diff` implementation so that it is based on `equals` and not `hashCode`

Comment: @GeorgePligor You generally need to override `hashCode` when you change `equals` -- that's not optional, it is the contract of the `hashCode` API every class inherits from `Object`, and it is described on both the `hashCode` and the `equals` JavaDoc. If you don't do that, your code is broken, period.

Comment: What you are saying is probably correct but either way I think it is silly. I would never design it like that. No offence to you but to the ones who implicitly create these kinds of restrictions that you need to learn, because the compiler will never tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> object ListTest {
     | 
     |   trait AbstractTest 
     |   case class Test (stringHolder: JStringHolder) extends AbstractTest {
     |     override def toString = stringHolder.toString ()
     |     override def equals (ot: Any) : Boolean = {
     |       stringHolder.equals (ot.asInstanceOf [Test].stringHolder)
     |     }
     |   }
     | 
     |   def main (args : Array [String]) : Unit = {
     |     val a = Test (new JStringHolder ("a"))
     |     val b = Test (new JStringHolder ("b"))
     |     val c = Test (new JStringHolder ("c"))
     |     val l1 = List (a, b)
     |     val l2 = List (b, c)
     |     println (l1.diff (l2))
     |     println (l1.intersect (l2))
     |     println (l1.union (l2))
     |   }
     | }
defined module ListTest

scala>  ListTest.main (null) 
List(a)
List(b)
List(a, b, b, c)
```

The first Test(JStringHolder("b")) is not == the second.